# How to identify the Hot and Neutral wiring in an old light fixture?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I'm trying to install a new light fixture and found the old wiring a bit confusing. Would appreciate some help answering the following questions:

1. How do I know which wire is the hot one and which the neutral one? Is the only way getting a voltage tester?
2. Why does one wire appear as two joined ones? What's the reason for it?
3. Am I correct that this old light fixture doesn't have a ground wire? If so, what should I do with the ground wire that comes with the new light fixture?

Thanks in advance[image: old fixture]

@ThreePaseEel This is how it looks: [image: Back of the box]

@Harper - Resinstate Monica: It was attached to the old lamp in the following way: The single wire to three wires coming from the lamp and the tied pair to another three wires coming from the lamp, see this picture [image: connection to the old lamp]

Comment: Can you get us a photo looking into the back of the box please? That'd help us with question #3 in particular

Comment: This could be easier than that.  Which wires was the old fixture attached to?  Was it attached where we see? (one wire to the single and one wire to the tied pair)?

Comment: for #3 in old homes I have seen a copper wire attached to the metal bracket the other end to the light fixture. Is it advisable or safe? dont know